# Count the integers in a string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a string named line that is a bunch of integers.

```
String line = 1 2 3 4 5 65 70
```

I made a scanner called lin for line.

```
Scanner lin = new Scanner(line);
```

I now want to count the number of integers in line.

I tried

```
while (lin.hasNextInt()){
    size++;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Java doesn't give any errors while compiling but just seems to run in an infinite loop. Help? Could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

By calling `hasNextInt()` you are just asking it if there is something left to consume, but not actually consuming it.

Try this:

```
while(lin.hasNextInt()) {
    lin.nextInt();  // Consumes the int
    size++;
}
```

Having said that, there are other ways to solve this problem (parsing the String input using String.split() and the seeing if what you have is an `Integer` would be a good way).

```
String line = "1 2 3 4 5 65 70"
String parts[] = line.split("\\s");
int size = 0;
for(String part : parts) {
    try {
       Integer.parseInt(part);
       size++;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       // What we parsed was NOT a number, catch the exception and move on.
    }
}
System.out.println("Found " + size + " numbers.");
```

That way, if your input contains "1 a 2", you will account for the "a" in there. Of course, if your input is guaranteed to be all numbers and whitespace, you could just get the length of `parts`, but I'm not so trusting with guaranteed input formats.

Comment: ok that made it worse. it now is giving me a ton of errors but from other things i think ugh but thanks!!! you did fix that part

Comment: Cool, glad that helped. Post your other errors after you've made an attempt to fix them and we can work them out with you if you need help.

Comment: might you happen to know what a NoSuchElementException is and if it's related to this?

Comment: It generally means that an iterator has run out of things to give you. Check out the other solution I've posted where you read an entire line in and then split it on whitespace. That might be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String line ="1 2 3";
 String array[] = line.split(" ");
 value = array.length;

 value = line.split(" ").length; // in one line
```

Is an alternative method. (But doesn't check if they are integers)